# Can I access the value of a stored procedure parameter within the stored proc, using the JavaScript API

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Can I access the value of a stored procedure parameter within the stored proc, using the JavaScript API?

I.e.:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure myproc1(param1 BOOLEAN)
    returns STRING
    language JAVASCRIPT
    comment = 'x'
    execute as CALLER
    as $$
        const x = function1(param1);
```

This results in
Uncaught reference error: param1 is not defined in myproc1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameters should be uppercase:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure myproc1(param1 BOOLEAN)
returns STRING
language JAVASCRIPT
comment = 'x'
execute as CALLER
as $$
    const x = function1(PARAM1);
    ...
```

[Case-sensitivity in JavaScript Arguments](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-javascript#case-sensitivity-in-javascript-arguments)

> Using uppercase identifiers (especially argument names) consistently across your SQL statements and JavaScript code tends to reduce silent errors.

Comment: I had read that in the docs, and then forgot. Thanks!!!